# find couple of objects from a dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, bigdata

How can I avoid the two `for` loops and optimize my code to be able to handle big data?

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
array = np.array([[1,'aaa','bbb'],[2,'ccc','bbb'],[3,'zzzz','bbb'],[4,'eee','zzzz'],[5,'ccc','bbb'],[6,'zzzz','bbb'],[7,'aaa','bbb']])
df= pd.DataFrame(array)
l=[]
for i in range(len(df)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(df)):
        if (df.loc[i][1] == df.loc[j][1]) & (df.loc[i][2] == df.loc[j][2]):
            l.append((df.loc[i][0],df.loc[j][0]))
```

[image: Screenshot of Jupyter notebook]

Comment: The time-complexity can't be lowered quite much, but you can lower the average case time by sorting the dataset before processing it and also using some Pandas function to restrict the dataset to the rows having repeated values or group by the joined columns.

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: Formatted code and embedded image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by the second and third column. Then use the combination function: `chain` and `combinations`.

```
from itertools import combinations
list(chain(*df.groupby(by=[1, 2])[0].apply(lambda x: combinations(x, 2))))
[('1', '7'), ('2', '5'), ('3', '6')]
```

Change the dataset a bit.

```
array = np.array([[1,'aaa','bbb'],[2,'ccc','bbb'],[3,'zzzz','bbb'],
                  [4,'eee','zzzz'],[5,'ccc','bbb'],[6,'zzzz','bbb'],
                  [7,'aaa','bbb'], [8, "aaa", "bbb"], [9, 'zzzz','bbb']])
df = pd.DataFrame(array)

list(chain(*df.groupby(by=[1, 2])[0].apply(lambda x: combinations(x, 2))))

[('1', '7'),
 ('1', '8'),
 ('7', '8'),
 ('2', '5'),
 ('3', '6'),
 ('3', '9'),
 ('6', '9')]

list(chain(*df.groupby(by=[1, 2])[0].apply(lambda x: combinations(x, 2))))
1.67 ms ± 34.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: @c'estmoi no problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can group by columns `[1,2]` and then aggregate values from column `0` as follows:

```
In [91]: df.groupby([1,2])[0] \
           .agg(lambda x: tuple(x.values) if len(x)>1 else np.nan) \
           .dropna() \
           .tolist()
Out[91]: [('1', '7'), ('2', '5'), ('3', '6')]
```